# How to access a video from the raw folder using a variable?

Tags: android, variables, video, resources

This is my code:

```
VideoView vd;
vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview2);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                        + R.raw.video1;
                vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
                vd.start();
```

This works, but i want the R.raw.video1 to be a string becaus i have a lot of videos to play.

So what i want is this:

```
String videoResource = "R.raw.video1"
 String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                            + videoResource;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, how do i get it to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the identifier of the resource for that to work, which can be retrieved by its name using:

```
int id = getResources().
    getIdentifier("name_of_resource", "id", getPackageName());
```

So your new code would become:

```
int videoResource = getResources().
    getIdentifier("video1", "raw", getPackageName());
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + videoResource;
```